# Weekly Chat Writing Topics: Winter 2013

Tags: discussion, chat

We meet Tuesdays in [The Overlook Hotel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) starting at 12pm Eastern time (1700 UTC) and generally wrap up anywhere from 2pm to 4pm Eastern, depending on how much people feel like chatting. The schedule is posted here, and we are looking to start a second session for people who can't make it during those times.

We have an informal writing exercise every week. Chatters are free to participate or not, and to ask for critique or not. All are welcome to come, read, and discuss; **completing the exercise is not required**.

Chatters are encouraged to post their exercises on their blog or other website, or by using Pastebin or Google docs, or by pretty much any method that allows the chatter to share a link in chat.

Chatters who post on their blogs may optionally include the following site-promotional boilerplate, provided to us by Mr.Shiny and New:

> This blog post is a writing exercise from writers.stackexchange.com. Visit the Writers chat room every Tuesday for new writing exercises. This week's exercise: [the text of the exercise]

About the writing exercises:

- The criteria for the weekly exercises are posted and pinned in the chat room.
- Please share only a link to avoid cluttering the room with criss-crossing text walls.

About the timed exercises:

- The topic will be announced in chat when everyone is ready.
- Volunteers may give a topic if they want to. Please coordinate with the host if you want to suggest the timed writing topic.
- After ten minutes, the host will declare that time is up.
- Please use the same sharing method as the weekly exercises (paste a link).

All exercises are for fun. We want you to have a good time writing and talking about writing, as well as have an excuse to sit and write at least once a week. If you have suggestions for writing exercises, feel free to post them here, or better yet, come to chat and discuss them! See you there.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will be updated with the current exercises. Please feel free to post suggestions.

**For the February 5th, 2013 chat**, we'll write three to five paragraphs on the topic of *punishment*.

**For the Jan 29, 2013 chat**, we'll write a 500 (roughly) word short story with an unexpected ending.

**For the Jan 15, 2013 chat**, write a paragraph or so of description. Rewrite it as a narrative, then as a dialogue. If you want, you can rewrite it a final time, integrating these three styles.

Comment: How about one on Purple Prose for the week of Valentine's Day? @Aerovistae and I were just discussing how this answer still makes us both giggle: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/how-do-you-avoid-purple-prose/1159#1159