# Stack Improvement Drive: Writers

Tags: discussion

Greetings from Stack Exchange HQ! I am here to check in on the site and see if there’s any way the Community Growth team from Stack Exchange can help you improve it. Note that this is a more hands-on, site-by-site and case-by-case basis evaluation, ***not*** related to the [Quality Evaluations](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=self-evaluation) already done on this site.

We’ve started keeping an eye on each site's metrics and how they fluctuate over time and compare to other sites that were launched at similar times. Writers was launched alongside **[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)**, **[IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)** and [**Homebrewing**](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/) in November 2010. Of those four, Writers and Homebrewing have yet to graduate, and Writers has the lowest (but not by much) visitors and questions per day average. I don't say that to discourage anyone; I say that to properly the convey the starting conditions of this site's *meteoric rise*. This is a good site. Writers has a 99% answer rate, which is something that *well over the majority* of our sites cannot claim. Plus I'm very pleased to see your community taking initiative with things like the [Weekly Chat](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/633/weekly-chat-writing-topics-winter-2013). That's great!

Here are some resources and ideas for enabling improvement, with links to Meta posts on other sites as examples:

- To improve visitors per day, try sharing your questions via other social media sites you use (click on the “share” button below any question). There is a badge for sharing that can be awarded multiple times: the Announcer badge. We can [start a contest](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/announcer-badge-reward) wherein users who get the Announcer badge get a prize.
- To improve the number of questions asked per day, we can start hosting [Topic of the Week events](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-jan-28th), where tags are chosen by the community and any questions within that tag during a set period of time are eligible for a prize.
- To help diversify the site's content, thus welcoming a wider range of writers, we could try a [Scope Expansion project](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/scope-expansion-project-update-jan-21-hiatus), wherein 10 little-used (but valuable) tags are selected and questions in those tags are randomly rewarded.

Personally, I think the area we need to concentrate on is **questions per day** (as evidenced by the [Writers - Area 51 page)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers). I would like to get the questions per day up to at least 5/day.

We are relying on you, the core user community, to decide whether or not any of these ideas are worth implementing. If so, we will spearhead the effort! You have our attention and also a modest budget with which to launch some of these initiatives.

If any users of Writers.SE have any other suggestions of what we can try to improve on these metrics, or any other element of the site you see as problematic, please leave an answer to this meta post.

Additionally, we know you are excited about the potential for our sites but please keep this meta post focused on things you, as the collective community, can do as opposed to feature requests or larger branding campaigns. We want your ideas, so please make them separate meta posts so we can keep all these discussions focused!

Comment: We tried a topic of the week event a while back.  One of the topics (collaborative authorship) brought some great questions, but it petered out pretty fast.

Comment: Yup. Although it may be worth giving it a crack again - and prizes are nice; they add incentive and give us something to publicize.

Comment: I support both the Topic of the Week and the Scope Expansion initiatives. I've seen arguments against trying to deliberately "seed" the site, but I think that's where we need to be going now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think if the goal is to increase the site's content and get the Qs/day increased, Scope Expansion is the way to go (as it covers many topics at once, as opposed to Topic of the Week which handles one at a time).