# Scope Expansion Project

Tags: discussion

This is being done in hopes that it will add a healthy dose of questions in topics that are currently under-represented here, and thus expanding the reach of the site. This is part of the **[Stack Improvement Drive](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/stack-improvement-drive-writers)**.

This will also address one thing holding Writers.SE back. On the [Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers), you can see that Writers.SE has **1.6 questions asked per day**, when **15** is the sign of a healthy Beta site. Right now, the goal with the Scope Expansion Project is to get the **Qs/Day up to 5** by the end of February.

**How it works:** There will be tags monitored each week. Each person who [asks a question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize.

**How to enter:** [Ask a question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to one of the topics below and tag it accordingly. Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win a Stack Exchange swag package of exclusive merchandise.

The question must have a score of 0 or greater and not be closed or deleted at the time of the drawing to be eligible. **Users may only win once in a four week period.**

**Winners will be selected every Monday at 2PM UTC**.

**Choosing the tags:** If you have suggestion for tags to be included future topic, please leave them as answers or comments to this post. Similarly if you think any tags should be removed due to lack of usefulness or appropriateness, leave that information as well.

---

**Current Tags:**

TBD

---

**What I need from you, the community:**

**What tags will be included in this project?** Another way of looking at it: **what topics do we want to encourage?** Right now the site is predominantly about [fiction](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction), specifically of the [novel](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) persuasion. My thinking was we could highlight [technical-writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing), [journalism](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journalism), [screenwriting](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenwriting), [poetry](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), [scientific-publishing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-publishing) and/or [blogs](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogs). **What do you think of this assessment?**

Please comment if you think this is a good starting point, or leave an answer with your suggestions for tags to include. I would like to launch the Project by **Monday, February 11th**, so please make your suggestions and vote on them by then. Once the Project launches, the tags are not set in stone! So keep on suggesting tags and ways you think we can meet our 5 Qs/Day goal.

Comment: the tag should be [tag:blog], not [tag:blogs]

Comment: I agree with your assessment, and particularly suggest technical writing (some user base here but not much), blogs (everybody's got 'em, it seems), and either journalism or scientific publishing as a way to reach out to people who aren't currently in evidence here.

Comment: I agree - all of those are good choices for tags to focus on.

Comment: these are all good tags, although I vote for blogS, not blog.

Comment: There already is an existing [blog](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) tag, so I set [blogs](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogs) up as a synonym.

Comment: I'm going to post several answers so tags can be voted on individually.  (My collective comment was probably unhelpful - sorry!)

Answer (score 6):

Suggestion: [technical-writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing), because we have a small user base in this topic here (so people will get answers) but could stand to grow it.

Comment: Might be worth noting that this option is the most likely to interest users on the large SE sites. I'm not sure what the protocol is for cross-site promotion, but there are definitely programmers out there who get stuck doing occasional tech writing despite having little or no training for it.

Comment: @C.A.McCann, good point!  We need to find a way to reach those people.  I wonder if any of our current questions in this tag are promotion-worthy, as a way of drawing people in?

Comment: Well, [this question](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/6377/4373) would make an excellent hook, especially if the title were tweaked to make the connection to software development more explicit, for essentially the same reason that the OP asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Have put up a few community ads leading to the site, tech writing ones on [Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5547/74535) and [Webmasters](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/937/23328), and I renewed the writing chat ads on [Scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2654/33) and [EL&U](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3401/161).

Comment: Both ads are still short of the threshold needed to actually appear--anyone who participates on either of those sites and thinks the ads are a good idea, please consider voting.

Answer (score 6):

Suggestion: [queries](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/queries), because it's a well-defined task with a lot of intricacies and a fair amount of detail available in various places around the web. This brings us back to novel writers, but not exclusively, and it aims us at a different part of the writing process.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like us to add [poetry](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) because I think there's a lot of potential there. If we can scare up more poets, they're a close bunch that'll readily give feedback to each other in the form of answers, and then, presumably, more questions.

Comment: I don't know how to add the poetry tag as a linked tag, but if anyone would care to do so in an edit, be my guest.

Comment: Done.  You can reference a tag by putting "tag:tag_name" in square brackets.  (See the edit diff if that wasn't clear.  You can see the edit diff by clicking on the text that says "edited" above my user name at the bottom of your answer.)

Comment: Also, welcome to meta JAM!

Comment: Thanks @MonicaCellio

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion: [blogs](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogs), because they're widespread so lots of our users probably have relevant experience and questions.  Also note that personal blogs and corporate/organizational blogs may have some different characteristics, so we should try to encourage both.

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion: [journalism](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journalism), as a way to reach out to an area we're not serving well now (6 questions at this writing).

Answer (score 4):

Even within fiction, there's a lot of genres we've hardly touched. We've got a lot of science fiction and fantasy, but I'd love to see more questions on tags like [romance](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance), [mystery](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery), [thriller](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thriller), [historical](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical), etc.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding [academic-writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing) too?